# How to format a url in order to navigate directly to a specific place in the site?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this template [agency](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/), which is built with bootstrap v.3. In the portfolio, when you click one of the projects, a page is shown with more info.. How can I format the link, in order to navigate directly to that page?
I added #portfolioModal1 at the end of the url but it doesnt work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a script for this, like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967735/toggle-bootstrap-modal-with-url-and-hash)

Use this:

```
<script>
  if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $(hash).modal('toggle');
  }
  $('.portfolio-link').click(function(){
       window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
  });
</script>
```

Call it like this:

```
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/#portfolioModal1
```