# Is there a way to open a Bootstrap Modal dialog from an external link say another website?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to open up a Bootstrap Modal dialog box from an external page say from say a website A to open a Bootstrap Modal in website B?

In the sense that when a user clicks a button on Website A, it links up and opens up a Bootstrap Modal on website B.

The implementation is say you share some code with a user on Website A to include it on their website then can load and open a modal in your website B.

Both not hosted on the same server. Anyone?

Comment: if you aware of socket then you can do it.

Comment: Not if you are not in control of site B. They must implement the functionality to open the modal. Usually this is done by passing the ID of the target element via the URI fragment.

Comment: @04FS I am in control of site B, the host of the modal. I want to share some code with third parties on site say A to open the modal on B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967735/toggle-bootstrap-modal-with-url-and-hash